# android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling : FusedLocationProvider API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am trying to create a background location tracker using `Google FusedLocationProvider API`. I have used Pending Intent for the same and created an `IntentService` class. I have also added a notification to notify user about the running location tracker. However, when I run the application, I can't see any notification, instead I am getting following warning in logcat:

```
W/Intent: Failure filling in extras
                                       android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult
                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2077)
                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
                                           at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
                                           at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
                                           at android.os.Bundle.putAll(Bundle.java:302)
                                           at android.content.Intent.fillIn(Intent.java:6367)
                                           at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:210)
                                           at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:192)
                                           at android.content.IIntentSender$Stub.onTransact(IIntentSender.java:64)
                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I am even not able to identify if my `PendingIntent` is working fine or not.

**Here is my `IntentService` Class:**

```
public class LocationHandlerService extends IntentService {

    Location mLocation;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public LocationHandlerService() {
        super("Services.LocationHandlerService");
    }


  /*  @Override
    public void setIntentRedelivery(boolean enabled) {
        super.setIntentRedelivery(true);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        ResultReceiver locationReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.RECEIVER);

        if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {

            LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
            mLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            setupNotification();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(Constants.BUNDLE, mLocation);
            locationReceiver.send(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, bundle);

        }
    }

    //Setup Notification
    private void setupNotification() {

        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.location_start_notification)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.location_notification))
                .setContentText("Lat: " + mLocation.getLatitude() + ", Long: " + mLocation.getLongitude())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        stopForeground(true);

    }

    // Creating constants to report the results of the Location Update process
    public final class Constants {

        public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.svtech.thirdeye.thirdeye";
        public static final String RECEIVER = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RECEIVER";
        public static final int RESULT_DATA_KEY = 9;
        public static final String BUNDLE = PACKAGE_NAME + ".BUNDLE";
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help????

Comment: I am running it on Android 4.2.2, API 17 @Ironman

Comment: search on google there are many similar question to this.

Comment: I googled it and found this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197296   how do I find out if this is problem with google API or with my code??? I could not find a workable solution...@Ironman

Comment: I think it is bug.

Comment: Does that mean I can't run location tracker in background using `FusedLocationAPI`??? @Ironman

Comment: and why notification is not working??? @Ironman